# Are failed login credentials logged?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, logs, login, password

Are failed login credentials logged in any way in Linux, especially what is being entered as the username? Would it be possible that, when someone accidentally enters the login password into a username prompt, the input is written to some log file in plain text?

Comment: Look over the answers to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235213/linux-log-what-username-and-password-was-tried

Comment: At least for local logins on my Ubuntu 18.04 system, this behavior is determined by the `LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB` parameter in `/etc/login.defs` and the default is `no` (so that auth.log just shows something like `FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty2' FOR 'UNKNOWN'`). FYI the situation you describe is mentioned in the discussion of `LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB` in the login.defs man page.

Comment: @NasirRiley: I read that thread, but found it inconclusive

Comment: @steeldriver: Thx, will look it up. Any idea if this also applies to Debian and LMDE?

Comment: @david no I don't - that's largely why I didn't post an answer. In particular, I'm not sure if `login.defs` is guaranteed to be used on newer systems with things like systemd-logind and how it may be affected by various PAM modules.

Comment: @steeldriver: At least `/etc/login.defs` exists, `LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB` is indeed set to `No` and there is a warning in the comment: `# WARNING: Unknown usernames may become world readable. See #290803 and #298773 for details about how this could become a security concern`

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible that, when someone accidentally enters the login password into a username prompt, the input is written to some log file in plain text?

Yes, this is indeed possible. This is why, as a security measure, you should change your password ASAP if you mistakenly entered it instead of your username.

The above behavior occurs, for instance, if the `LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB` config value in `/etc/login.defs` is set to true, as said in the comments.

From the manpage:

```
   LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB (boolean)
       Enable display of unknown usernames when login failures are
       recorded.

       Note: logging unknown usernames may be a security issue if an
       user enter her password instead of her login name.
```